# Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function - Fraction Slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use fractionslider on my wordpress site but its not working and getting above error.

Getting error for the following code

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  $('.slider').fractionSlider();
});
```

[image: Undefined is not defined ERROR Javascript Uncaught TypeError]

This is the order in which files are added.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='_tk-bootstrap-css'  href='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/includes/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css?ver=3.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='_tk-fontawesome-css'  href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=3.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='_tk-style-css'  href='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/style.css?ver=3.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='_tk-fractioncss-css'  href='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/includes/plugins/fractionSlider/css/fractionslider.css?ver=3.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/sample/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/sample/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/includes/plugins/fractionSlider/jquery.fractionslider.min.js?ver=3.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/includes/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?ver=3.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/includes/js/bootstrap-wp.js?ver=3.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/sample/wp-content/themes/sample/includes/js/myscript.js?ver=3.9.2'></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you've got some code that's calling `jQuery.noConflict()` which would result in `$` being undefined. It should be easy to just add a `console.log()` to check that, or just do it in the debugger.

Comment: @Pointy I am not an expert in javascript but I tried to folder search above code and it doesnt exist